# Mongoengine & Django-allauth for facebook login

Tags: mongoengine, django-allauth

I want to use django-allauth in conjunction with MongoEngine in my Django project. The idea being that new users will be created in mongodb instead of mysql. I have added the necessary steps to my configuration to enable mongoengine within my django settings file.

Now, I am trying to enable django-allauth so that users can sign in with facebook and their account gets created in mongodb.

So far my settings file looks like this

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    # Required by allauth template tags
    "django.core.context_processors.request",
    # allauth specific context processors
    "allauth.account.context_processors.account",
    "allauth.socialaccount.context_processors.socialaccount",
)


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount',
)

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'mongoengine.django.auth.MongoEngineBackend',
    "allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend",
)
```

How can I get both to work together ?